# Customizing exceptions in python. How to log errors?

Tags: python, inheritance, logging, exception

I am customizing exceptions in my python code. I have inherited exception class in to other and now defining some custom errors as classes derived from my custom exception class like this:

```
class DataCollectorError(Exception): pass
class ParamNullError(DataCollectorError) : pass
class ParamInvalidTypeError(DataCollectorError) : pass
```

I am raising these exceptions in my python function like:

```
def READ_METER_DATA (regIndex, numRegisters, slaveUnit):
    if not regIndex:
        raise ParamNullError, "register index is null"

    if not numRegisters:
        raise ParamNullError, "number of registers should not be null"

    if not slaveUnit:
        raise ParamNullError, "Meter Id should not be null"

    if(isinstance(regIndex, int) == False):
        raise ParamInvalidTypeError, "register index passed is not int"

    if(isinstance(numRegisters, int) == False):
        raise ParamInvalidTypeError, "number of registers passed is not int"
```

Now I want to log error messages into log file using logger but don't know where to do it.

1. should I do it by putting that function code in try catch but then how will I be getting those error messages
2. should I do it inside custom error class I have created (`DataCollectorError`)
3. or in individual error classes like `ParamNullError` etc.

But then I don't know where and how to get that error message to log them.

Comment: `if not isinstance(regIndex,int):` is better style, and always avoid comparison to boolean unless that's really what you mean.  Furthermore, these particular example checks look better served by `assert`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the standard [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html); it'll log your exceptions *with* the exception message out of the box.

When your application catches an exception, use the [`logging.exception()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) to log it; the exception is automatically added to the log entry:

```
log = logging.getLogger('some-identifier')

try:
    #
except DataCollectorError:
    log.exception('An error occurred')
```

Exceptions have a `.args` tuple argument by default, and the first value in that tuple is your message.

Some style feedback on your code:

- Don't test for `== False`. Rather, use `not`:

  ```
  if not isinstance(regIndex, int):
  ```
- Raise instances of your exception:

  ```
  raise ParamNullError("register index is null")
  ```

  rather than the `raise class, message` style, to make it easier to move to Python 3.

Comment: I want that message that i passed while raising that exception. How will i get it? and i also wanna ask that after raising these exception s will this code go to next line or function will exit??

Comment: @InderpalSingh: Raising an exception means that the normal code flow is interrupted. Until you catch and handle the exception, functions exit *immediately* and the next line is not executed.

Comment: @InderpalSingh: You want to read up on how exceptions work in the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) perhaps?

Comment: thanks but can you please tell me how to have that message passed in custom exception?  will DataCollectorError will return that message ? @Martijn

Comment: @InderpalSingh: Please see the tutorial. Your `DataCollectorError` exception will include that message as `.args[0]`; I stated this in my answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but i was asking about getting the message i passed while raising that error @martijn

Comment: @InderpalSingh: I know. You can access it as `.args[0]` on the exception instance. See the tutorial on how to catch an exception and print the message.